# Getting Error Message Error: spawn EACCES using IONIC Framework

Tags: ionic-framework, cross-platform

I am trying to learn ionic cross platform tool. i have setup thing required for example application `ionic serve`  is working fine but when i try to run `sudo ionic build android`  or `sudo ionic run/emulate android` it returns with error message.

```
Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1162:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:995:9)
    at Object.exports.spawn (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:103:31)
    at runScriptViaChildProcessSpawn (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:189:23)
    at runScript (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:132:16)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:115:20
    at _fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
```

i am unable to understand what does its mean. i have google this thing but after appling all of those solutions i got same error. i ll highly thankful if any one can tell me what is going wrong with me.

Answer (score 34):

The issue is with the command `010_add_platform_class.js` missing execute permission.

You could use `chmod +x hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js` to give execute permission.

I found this solution on the Ionic framework forum at the below link.
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-fix-this-error-spawn-eacces/20490/6

Comment: This "grant permission" command does not work for me, I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 4):

**Successfully Worked**

```
chmod +x hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
```

Comment: This answer is a rehash of @bkowshik's Aug 31 2015 answer (most upvoted).

Answer (score 4):

First try to give execution permission to one file in hooks folder (`010_add_platform_class.js`), you can use this command:

```
chmod +x hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
```

If it does not work, change the permissions of complete files in sdk folder by:

```
chmod +x -R /home/username/Android/Sdk
```

If you are installed `gradle` in separate, give permission to that folder also:

```
chmod +x -R /home/username/Android/gradle-2.3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `ionic hooks add` if other fix have not worked

Answer (score 2):

While the given solution did take me a step further, adding execute permissions to android sdk was also needed.

```
chmod +x -R /home/username/Android/Sdk
```

see [Error: spawn EACCES when trying to build Ionic app in Ubuntu 15.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728554/error-spawn-eacces-when-trying-to-build-ionic-app-in-ubuntu-15-10)

Comment: Yuck - make the entire sdk executable including config files, the README file etc. Maybe restrict this to the shell scripts>!>!>!

This solution did work for me, however, by just making the gradlew script executable

Answer (score 2):

I tried this, it's working

```
      chmod +x hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
```

Answer (score -1):

Try running this in your app folder :

- `ionic hooks add`