# getting Error: spawn EACCES while ionic build android in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

i developed one project in ionic2

while i am doing ionic build android i am getting this error

[image]

my ionic info is

Cordova CLI: 6.3.0

Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10

Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.36

Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.19

OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Node Version: v4.4.7

I searched in google but no solution works for me..

How can i fix this Bug?

Comment: i think its because of your path

Answer (score 29, accepted):

hit this command

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /appfolder
```

It is caused by permission problem. More info on problem [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-fix-this-error-spawn-eacces/20490).

> If this does not solve your problem then its probably issue of permission in your user profile directory. Try above command on user directory. It will take some time to apply permission.

Regards.

Comment: is it giving any error ? did you refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32314465/6449750

Comment: can you try to build project after moving project to another location ? Try command on your desktop folder too.

Comment: then its problem of your user directory in OS volume. try hitting command on that. i had this same problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120121/discussion-between-hardik-vaghani-and-ramya).

Comment: Works. I was missing the x in the "a+rwx". Thanks.

Answer (score 52):

This is Permission Error While Building App

You Need to Give Permission Gradle

sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/Android\ Studio\ 3.0\ Preview.app/Contents/gradle

Enjoy :)

Comment: My Pleasure Thanks :)

Comment: Solved my issue! Thanks

Comment: Krunal, you have no idea how many headaches your solution has spared me. Been looking everywhere. Thank you for saving me a lot of time and frustration!

Comment: Thanks you saved me!

Comment: Should use `+x` instead of 777. This make it executable without effecting other permission settings on `gradle`

Comment: I had to do this targeting ..../bin for it to work. Eg. `sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin`

Answer (score 8):

Use the verbose when you make your cordova build:

```
cordova build -verbose
```

It will return to you the path that requires the `chmod +x`

Answer (score 7):

I was using Cordova to run my Hybrid app on my Android device, and I got this error twice during the unsuccessful build ...

Error: spawn EACCES

@Krunel Vaghela's answer above helped me somewhat ...

> This is Permission Error While Building App
>
> You Need to Give Permission Gradle
>
> sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/Android\ Studio\ 3.0\ Preview.app/Contents/gradle

But I kept having this error: 
  "chmod: -r: no such file or directory"

I was using this command:

```
[Sandis-Macbook-Pro:Users sandi$ sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle
```

Note that my Android app is named "Android Studio.app"  (with a space in the name).  Solution is to simply wrap the path in quotes like so:

```
[Sandis-Macbook-Pro:Users sandi$ sudo chmod -R 777 "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle"
```

NOTE: In order to find out which folder was having the permissions problem, I had to use this command:

```
sudo build -verbose
```

Which yielded the path to the permissions problem folder like this:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/sandi/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home
Running command: "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle" -p /Users/sandi/Desktop/CORDOVA_NOV16/HHUB_NOV17/hhub_CURRENT/platforms/android wrapper -b /Users/sandi/Desktop/CORDOVA_NOV16/HHUB_NOV17/hhub_CURRENT/platforms/android/wrapper.gradle
Error: spawn EACCES
```

So take the path after "Running command:" - put that, inside quotes, after the ...

```
chmod -r 777
```

And that's what saved my day.

Comment: Thank you. You explained everything. Though -verbose didn't work. But I got to build my ionic project finally. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, I got it fixed by giving 777 permissions on my Sdk folder : 
chmod -R 777 /YOURINSTALLOFANDROID/Sdk

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to **Android 3.2**, `gradle` version has been changed up to **4.6**.

So I had to use this following command to modify *gradle* file permission in my Mac Terminal.

```
sudo chmod 755 "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.6/bin/gradle"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove **"node_modules"** folder and **re-install** it using

```
sudo npm i
```

Hope It get works ..Thanks..!