# chmod does not grant access to resolve the Error: spawn EACCES

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using node v6.4.0, npm v3.10.3, and ionic 1. I'm gettiing `Error: spawn EACCES` when I tried to add ios platform by: `sudo ionic platform add ios` or `sudo cordova platform add ios`.

Then I tried `sudo ionic hooks add`, and `sudo chmod +x hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js` which was discussed in [How to fix Error: spawn EACCES](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-fix-this-error-spawn-eacces/20490/6).

When it didn't work for me, I tried  `sudo chmod 777 /Users/<username>/.config/configstore/insight-cordova.json` and `sudo chmod 744 ~/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json`. They didn't help me either. I want to know is there anything else I'm missing which can cause this error?

Comment: try again with sudo chmod 777 -R

Comment: @owaishnif786 it didn't solve the problem for me. I got  `chmod: -R: No such file or directory`, but I can find the path  `hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js` in shell.

Comment: offcourse you have to provide the path path where you have to set the permission at all forum they are setting permission recursivly so you also need to set permission recrusively. sudo chmod 777 -R path

Comment: @owaishanif786 well, I also tried `sudo chmod 777 -R hooks/`, but I get the same error `chmod: -R: No such file or directory`

Comment: Refer this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38767207/6449750 and comments too, may be it can help.

Comment: @HardikVaghni This didn't help. In http://stackoverflow.com/q/39043429/3781320, another person explained what is actually wrong.

Comment: Please Find Answer Number Second : [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767126/getting-error-spawn-eacces-while-ionic-build-android-in-ubuntu-14-04/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an permission issue obviously, and when you are using `sudo chmod 777 -R hooks/` you are doing it wrong. Because the correct syntax is `sudo [Your mode] [Your behavior flag] [Your path]`. The easiest way to solve this problem is sudo as super user: `sudo su` on the root folder. Then You can directly run `ionic platform add ios`

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me.

1. Install dos2unix by using "sudo apt-get install dos2unix" this
   command.
2. Then run this command "dos2unix 010_add_platform_class.js".
3. After that add platform again.