# chmod 777 -R on existing path getting chmod: -R: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, macos, permissions, chmod

I wanted to grant operation access using `sudo chmod 777 -R <path>` on mac, I double checked the given path, and it's existing and no typos, but I still got `chmod: -R: No such file or directory`. Any ideas about why I'm getting this error?

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777 <path>`. The `-R` switch should be used the actual permission.

Comment: That's right. I thought -R is just a flag that I can add anywhere before the <path>, which I shouldn't.

Comment: You can always check out the syntax for a command using `man <command>` if you are unsure how to use it.

Comment: How do I read "should be used the actual permission"?

Comment: @Trejkaz yes his sentence is ambigious, he means `-R` flag should be used before the actual permission like `sudo chmod -R 777 <path>`

Comment: @AwaisNasir that's not just ambiguous, that's straight-up missing a word.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look at the synopsis from the man page for `chmod` you will se the following:

> SYNOPSIS
>          chmod [OPTION]... MODE[,MODE]... FILE...
>          chmod [OPTION]... OCTAL-MODE FILE...
>          chmod [OPTION]... --reference=RFILE FILE...

The `-R` flag should be used before the actual file mode, so you need to call the command like this:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 <path>
```

Right now you are trying to set `777` permission on a file named `-R` which of course does not exist.

Comment: Ok, this explained. I've seen a lot of other people messing up the order as well.

Comment: And it needs to be a CAPITAL -R not lower case -r