# Not able to install non native cordova plugin in ionic v2

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am building an Ionic 2 mobile app. I want to get the IP address of network.

So I want to install the plugin `cordova-plugin-networkinterface`

```
https://github.com/salbahra/cordova-plugin-networkinterface
```

Below is my `ionic info`

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
    Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.1.3
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.1.2
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.1.2
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 2.1.0

System:

    Node       : v6.10.2
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.1 Build version 8E1000a 
    ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
    ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
    npm        : 4.5.0
```

But, when I try to install the plugin using command

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-networkinterface
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-networkinterface --save (exit code 1):

        Installing "cordova-plugin-networkinterface" for android
        ANDROID_HOME=/Users/ankarthik/Library/Android/sdk
        JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
        Subproject Path: CordovaLib
        Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-networkinterface': Error: spawn EACCES
        at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
        at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
        at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:378:9)
        at exports.spawn
        (/Users/ankarthik/Documents/projects/Juventus/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:134:31)
        at /Users/ankarthik/Documents/projects/Juventus/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js:261:16
        at _fulfilled
        (/Users/ankarthik/Documents/projects/Juventus/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
        at self.promiseDispatch.done
        (/Users/ankarthik/Documents/projects/Juventus/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
        (/Users/ankarthik/Documents/projects/Juventus/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
        at /Users/ankarthik/Documents/projects/Juventus/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:877:14
        at runSingle (/Users/ankarthik/Documents/projects/Juventus/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
        Error: spawn EACCES
```

Have already tried resolving the permission issue suggested at below link:

[getting Error: spawn EACCES while ionic build android in ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767126/getting-error-spawn-eacces-while-ionic-build-android-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Also have tried downgrading my Ionic CLI to 2.1.0 but still same error occurs. Am I missing out something here?

Comment: no brother.... error's same but scenario's different

Comment: have you tried removing the android platform folder and adding it again ? this is a permission issue .... try also sudo.

Comment: @Alberick0..... Thanks man!! I suppose it was permission issue. Readding platform android did work.

Comment: @Alberick0 could you please add that as an answer? It could help other SO user facing the same issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the android platform folder and add it again. It should fix your issue if not check for the folder permissions.